# What is a "regular way" contract?

Tags: united-states, stock-markets, sec

I was reading a stock brokerage firm's article on [Regulation NMS and Rule 611](https://www.schwab.com/legal/reg-nms-611), which says:

> The Order Protection Rule requires trading centers to establish and enforce procedures designed to prevent "trade-throughs"—trade executions at prices inferior to the best-priced quotes displayed by automated trading centers.

According to the SEC [final rules](https://www.sec.gov/rules/final/34-51808.pdf) ([17 CFR § 242.611 - Order protection rule](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/17/242.611)), there is an exception for contracts that are not "regular way":

> (b) Exceptions
>
> [...]
>
> (2) The transaction that constituted the trade-through was not a "regular way" contract.

But what is "regular way"? The SEC final rules document says:

> “Regular way” refers to bids, offers, and transactions that embody the standard terms and conditions of a market.  Thus, this exception applies to a transaction that was executed other than pursuant to standardized terms and conditions, for instance a transaction that has extended settlement terms.

What does this legalese mean? What is "regular way"? Is normal settlement for stocks (T+2) "regular way"? What about cash settlement for stocks and after-hours trades? What about the sale of stock at nominally low prices as part of a contract or will?

(Relevance to personal finance: I want to make sure that I always buy/sell at a price that is at least as good as the National Best Bid and Offer [NBBO]).

Comment: "_I want to make sure that I always buy/sell at a price that is at least as good as the National Best Bid and Offer [NBBO]_" As a normal "consumer" I'm pretty sure those regulations ensure that you will. I strongly suspect (but will try and confirm) that "_executed other than pursuant to standardized terms and conditions_" is for institutional-level deals where it will be obvious when the normal rules (the "regular way") doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make sure that I always buy/sell at a price that is at least as good as the National Best Bid and Offer [NBBO].

For a "regular" person, doing "regular" trades, the SEC rules you quote will ensure that this is the case. The "*Regular Way*" settlement terms (T+2) will apply, and the broker is obliged to find the best price. As far as I can see, you have to *explicitly* select non-standard settlement terms.

For instance, the page [**T+1 Early Stock Settlement**](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=13437) on *InteractiveBrokers* talks about the potential benefits of *opting for* T+1 settlement (*potentially* avoiding "accidental" Capital Gains tax for certain types of trade), but it seems clear that this is something you have to deliberately choose. It also notes (my emphasis):

> - T+1 Settlement is only available on certain equity securities at our discretion, and these securities may change from time to time. The executing broker reserves the right not to offer T+1 Settlement at any time and for any reason.
> - T+1 Settlement trades generally will be executed against an affiliate of the executing broker, which may profit or lose in connection with the transaction.
> - **You may pay a different or worse price** for shares you purchase for T+1 Settlement (i.e., for non-regular way settlement you may pay more than the best price offered in the market for regular way settlement). **In addition, certain price protection rules that apply to regular way settlement do not apply to T+1 trades**.